# How to use an if/elif inside a class when you need different parameters?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm doing a class to put inside all commands about keyboard of pygame, at least all that I need, but when I use if or else being equals to a "variable" I want to define later, it returns a error telling me it isn't defined.

I do not know enough to say in technical therms, sorry by mistakes. I started using button as a `key()` argument, and I got the same error, then I tried using `__init__()` but I can use it yet (not sure how), then I made in this way...

```
class control():
    def button(self, button):
        self.button = button
    def exit(self):
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    def key(self, axis, speed):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == self.button:
                axis = 0
                axis = speed


ctrl = control()
w = control().button(K_w)
s = control(K_s)
UP = control(K_UP)
DOWN = control(K_DOWN)


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        ctrl.exit()  
        w.key(y1, -5)
        s.key(y1, +5)
        UP.key(y2, -5)
        DOWN.key(y2, +5)
```

> ```
>  File "C:/Users/Smith/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/test0002.py", line 25, in <module>
>     w = control().button(K_w)
> NameError: name 'K_w' is not defined
> ```

I want to use the key function to define button, so I could take it later for every keyboard input instead write it all again each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message

> name 'K_w' is not defined

occures, bcause you've forgotten the module namespace.

The name of the constant is `pygame.K_w` rather than `K_w`. The constants are placed in the pygame module namespace.

Either use the *full* name of the constant:

```py
w = control().button(pygame.K_w)
```

or import the pygame constants See [*pygame.locals*](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/locals.html)

```py
from pygame.locals import *

# [...]

w = control().button(K_w)
```

---

Further the variables `w` is never defined, because `control()` does generate the object, but `button()` doesn't return any value. The method button should return `self`:

```py
class control():
    def button(self, button):
        self.button = button
        return self
```

But I recommend to implement a constructor in the class `control` rather than the method `button` (Of course you can do both):

```py
class control():
    def __init__(self, button=0):
        self.button = button

ctrl = control()
w = control(K_w)
s = control(K_s)
UP = control(K_UP)
DOWN = control(K_DOWN)
```

---

The method `key` has to return the new value of the parameter `axis`:

```py
class control():

    # [...]

    def key(self, axis, speed):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == self.button:
                axis = speed
        return axis

y1, y2 = 0, 0
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        ctrl.exit()  
        y1 = w.key(y1, -5)
        y1 = s.key(y1, +5)
        y2 = UP.key(y2, -5)
        Y2 = DOWN.key(y2, +5)
```